# how to upload (commit) my first project to git hub from xcode

Tags: xcode, git, github

I started commiting my project to github.

For that I created an account in github with email and password.

Then on the console I did inital stuff:

- cd project
- git init .
- git add .
- git commit -s

-> I did not commit (stopped without comment), because I expected to enter a password.

In Xcode I committed one file for testing, but I was supriced why I was not asked for a password. 
In the logs I see that it was published with a user, that I don't know : `user@users-Mac.local`

So I don't know where the file is published now for public !

Then I changed my name and email as follow:

- xcrun git config --global user.name 'xxxxx'
- xcrun git config --global user.email 'yyyyy'

But still I don't have to provide a password and I guess it is not working properly with my account.

Can anyone help me out ?

Comment: "So I don't know where the file is published now for public". It isn't. Git is a distributed version control system, and committing is a local operation. Only when you explicitly push your changes to a shared repository like GitHub will other users see your commit.

Answer (score 1):

Getting code onto GitHub has two main steps:

- `git commit` your changes
- `git push` to GitHub

Nothing's asking you for a password when you `commit`, because that's still totally local to your machine. Only when you `push` will you need to authenticate with GitHub.

Check out these guides to help you get started:

- [Git basics](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Git-Basics)
- [Set up Git with GitHub](https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git/#platform-all)

Comment: Thanks for helping. When I commited one file and when I do in XCODE -> Source Control -> push it pops up a dialog saying "no remotes available"

Comment: You'll need to [create a repo](https://help.github.com/articles/create-a-repo/) if you haven't yet, and then [add a remote](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-remote/).

Comment: Ok Thanks a lot . I understand the concept now. Thanks a lot !

Comment: @mcflysoft If the answer is correct please 'tick' it so that others can see it and the Author gets some credit. Thanks.